# Send data from both php and js to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to send data from php to php and in same time I also want to send data from js to php. I have one index.php which contains php and js part. In enrolled.php I want to collect my data. SQL injection or other security problems are not important. I do not get any error but it does not save to database.

Small part of index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
//smt....Not important
</head>
<body>
//smt....Not important
  <div id="dom-target" style="display: none;">
    <?php
          include_once "connection.php";

          session_start();
          $username = $_SESSION['username'];//coming from previous page.
          echo htmlspecialchars($username);   //for sending variable from php to js.
      ?>
</div>
   <script type = "text/javascript">
      $('#addmore').click(function(){ 
         var subjectone = $('#selectedsubjectone :selected').val();
         var courseone = $('#courseListone').val();
         var gradeone = $('#selectedGradeOne :selected').val();

         var div = document.getElementById("dom-target");
         var username = div.textContent;//these lines help to gett data from php
          document.getElementById("usernamee").innerHTML = username;//for checking
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "addenrolled.php",
                      data: {
                          // Send the username (js, not php)
                          username: username,
                          subject: subjectone,
                          course: courseone,
                          grade: gradeone
                      }, success: function(data) {
                         alert("sucess");
                      }
                  });
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

enrolled.php

```
<?php
    include_once "connection.php";

        $nick = $_POST['username'];
        $subject=$_POST['subject'];
        $course=$_POST['course'];
        $grade=$_POST['grade'];
        echo "$nick -- $subject -- $course -- $grade";    //for checking
        $prep = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO enrolledtable ('nickname', 'subject', 'course', 'grade') VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
        $prep->bind_param("ssss", $nick, $subject, $course, $grade);
        $send = $prep->execute();

        if ($send == TRUE) {
            echo "Courses added successfully";
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $con->error;
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }

 ?>
```

Comment: It's good that you're using prepared statements with placeholder values, but it's very important that the placeholders are *bare* and not decorated with things like quotes. This code will generate nothing but syntax errors. You can also skip creating single-use variables like `$nick` and just bind to the `$_SESSION` and `$_POST` directly.

Comment: Also try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== TRUE`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Comment: thanks for your interest. @tadman . How can I change $nick = $_SESSION['username']; and I think it is correct because I can get data with this method in my different php file.

Comment: Can you also help me about how can I transfer data with AJAX

Comment: Try doing things like `$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $_SESSION['username'], $_POST[...], ...)` instead. That can be a lot cleaner if you break out each argument, one per line, for organization purposes. Note that PDO is even better at this sort of thing since you can use named placeholders and call `execute(array("nick" => $_SESSION['username'], ...))`.

Comment: Try and send your data in like `data: { nickname: username, ... }` to ensure it gets encoded properly. Right now you're just smashing it together as a string without proper URI encoding, so that could be totally broken.

Comment: I try                           data: {username: username, subjectone: subjectone, courseone: courseone, gradeone: gradeone,}   but it is not working.

Comment: Check with your browser in the Network Inspector what it's sending and what response you get, then look in your error logs on the server for any insight into what went wrong.

Comment: when I print these informations with javascript subjectone, courseone and gradeone were printed but username have never printed without first lines in my index.php.

Comment: Sounds like you have some debugging to do to find out why.

Comment: I understand that  --- <?php
    include_once "connection.php";

    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    echo "$username";   
?> -----  prints username but I cannot use $username inside my <script></script>. So, firstly, I try to pass my data from php to js.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. `$username` means nothing to JavaScript. That variable does not exist unless you go out of your way to declare it *as a JavaScript variable* somehow, like `var username = <?php echo json_encode($username); ?>;` in your JavaScript `<script>` section. These are two completely different worlds, JavaScript cannot "see" your PHP variables, and vice-versa.

Comment: I try to do like that ----------------  var username = <?php include_once "connection.php"; session_start(); $_SESSION['username']; echo json_encode($username); ?>; --------but it is not working. I will try to send my data from php to js. @tadman

Comment: can you post the form code please.

Comment: I updated my code @julekgwa. There is no form it is complicated you can check with this link https://notepad.pw/share/nuu6dfdn

Comment: I send data from php to js successfully. But enrolled.php is not add these data to database.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `jQuery` to this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addmore').click(function(){ 
        var subjectone = $('#selectedsubjectone :selected').val();
        var courseone = $('#courseListone').val();
        var gradeone = $('#selectedGradeOne :selected').val();

        $.post('enrolled.php', {subjectone: subjectone, courseone: courseone, gradeone: gradeone, addmore: "yes"}, function(response){
            console.log(response);
        })

        });
    });
</script>
```

Then in your `PHP` modify the prepare statement to the following

```
$prep = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO enrolledtable (`nickname`, `subject`, `course`, `grade`) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
$prep->bind_param("ssss", $nick, $subject, $course, $grade);
$send = $prep->execute();
```

enrolled.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once "connection.php";

if (isset($_POST['addmore'])) {
    $nick = $_SESSION['username'];
    $subject=$_POST['subjectone'];
    $course=$_POST['courseone'];
    $grade=$_POST['gradeone'];
    // //echo "$nick -- $subject -- $course -- $grade";    //for checking
    $prep = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO enrolledtable (`nickname`, `subject`, `course`, `grade`) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
    $prep->bind_param("ssss", $nick, $subject, $course, $grade);
    $send = $prep->execute();

    if ($send == TRUE) {
        echo "Courses added successfully";
       // header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $con->error;
        //header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I deleted `if(isset($_POST['addmore']))` because AJAX call enrolled.php so it is not necessary and may cause error. In sql part `(nickname, subject, course, grade)` I wrote instead of `(`nickname`, `subject`, `course`, `grade`)`. `$(document).ready(function()` is not true I think because I want to load all page and user select something in several dropbox after that they click addmore button. So after click, the js should work. Is it correct or not (maybe I am wrong)?

Comment: did you try the code?, yes you can remove `$(document).ready()`

Comment: I try. I can print username, subject, course and grade with javascript. but when I send them to enrolled.php, I write   `echo "$nick -- $subject -- $course -- $grade";` and it is not working or giving error.

Comment: here is the problem `$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $nick, $subject, $course, $grade);` use `$prep->bind_param("ssss", $nick, $subject, $course, $grade);` instead

Comment: thank you but it is not enough for working. I use                   `$.post('addenrolled.php', {username: username, subject: subjectone, course: courseone, grade: gradeone}, function(response){
    console.log(response);`  it is same and working for me.

Comment: `$nick = $_POST['username'];
        $subject=$_POST['subject'];
        $course=$_POST['course'];
        $grade=$_POST['grade'];
        echo "$nick -- $subject -- $course -- $grade";`

echo does not print something. I cannot get anything with enrolled.php or maybe I cannot send.

Comment: don't use `$.post('addenrolled.php', {username: username, subject: subjectone, course: courseone, grade: gradeone}, function(response){ console.log(response);` use the one in my answer and follow what I did.

Comment: I have to add username, we delete if(isset so I delete addmore and I change with correct php file name.

Comment: index.php - [link](https://notepad.pw/share/46f1c76e0)  addenrolled.php [link](https://notepad.pw/share/as0t1wqq3)